# Relay Contact Rating (DC Power) at different DC voltages

Tags: voltage, relay, dc

To note, I have Google searched this question for the last 2 hours with many contradicting answer and searched Stackexchange with no clear answer.

I need to determine if a relay with a Contact Rating of 10A 250VAC/30VDC can handle 25A at 12VDC and if it would be able to handle lower amperages at higher DC voltages.

A few websites suggest as long as the power does not exceed 300W, any voltage/ current combination is okay and other websites say that is incorrect.

Attached is the [Relay Specifications](https://zofr.en.alibaba.com/product/323872048-209921153/DPDT_10A_8_PIN_JQX_13F_2Z_relay.html?spm=a2700.8304367.prewdfa4cf.2.73152c545AZwmk) for reference, however this is more of a general question about relays.

Thank you very much

Comment: Relay does't care about the power (well, in the sense stated in the question). The contact is a conductor which is passing current. If it is too high, it will overheat and burn/weld.

Comment: ... and once used its contact resistance will start to increase over time (pitting) which would lead to premature failure.  I'm an old fashioned engineer and I like a good safety margin. I'd probably choose something with a stated higher current rating (say 40A @12V) than **guess**  if a relay rated at 10A/higher voltage could handle 25A at a lower voltage. My gut feeling would be that it wouldn't be very reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to comply with all of :

From the datasheet:

- Max. Switching Voltage:250VAC/30VDC
- Max. Switching Current:10A
- Max. Switching Power:300W 2500VA

When NOT switching (so steady state on or off) the ratings are:

- Contact Rating(Res. Load):10A 250VAC/30VDC

And no, you cannot trade one for the other, so 10A max and 30V max independently.

Note also that the contact rating is for a resistive load, it will be much lower for switching a capacitive or inductive load.

Comment: Thank you @DanMills, I appreciate the quick response.

Everything you've said made sense, but I would like to confirm that regardless of the voltage, 5VDC, 12VDC, 29VDC, 10A should never be exceeded based off of the given manufacturing specifications, correct?

However, it also seems apparent now that 30VDC should not be exceeded, regardless of a lower amperage, correct?

Thank you very much for all your assistance.

Comment: Correct, 10A and 30V are both limiting values.

Comment: can you elaborate as to why Power does not play a roll in this? Thank you!

Comment: It does, hence the 300W (DC) or 2500VA (AC) switching limit which also applies independently (In this case you cannot exceed the power limit without also exceeding one of the other parameters, but that is not always the case).

Comment: @DanMills, it looks like the data sheet in this example mentioned "Res. Load" mentioned, meaning "resistive load".  If a relay just has "Control 10A 250VAC, 10A 30VDC load", how would you identify the type of load?   ... example: https://www.ebay.com/itm/10PCS-Relay-High-Level-Driver-Module-3V-3-3V-optocouple-Relay-Module-for-Arduino/331929215553?rt=nc&_trkparms=aid%3D555018%26algo%3DPL.SIM%26ao%3D2%26asc%3D50998%26meid%3D6ead449ce0634c73827926fe1a2402f7%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D4%26rkt%3D6%26mehot%3Dlo%26sd%3D352168898194%26itm%3D331929215553&_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851

Comment: If not specified, assume resistive load in a relay spec. However that SongLe part has a real datasheet (Assuming the ones you get are genuine)! https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/321/27115-Single-Relay-Board-Datasheet-709206.pdf , which specifies resistive and inductive load limits in the contact ratings section. I am fairly sure the alleged DC ratings from the CCC are a typo and should be AC ratings.  Given the part on your board has alleged ratings that do NOT match the datasheet from SongLe (The real ones have a 10A rating only for form A contacts at 240V) I would suspect fake parts and walk away.

Answer (score 0):

The values indicated for relays are separate and distinct. Max current is exactly that.. max current. Similarly max voltage is again separate.

Think about it this way.. When closed the voltage rating no longer applies since the relay shorts out the terminals and there is no voltage (Almost). Similarly, when open there ought to be no current. As such they are separate.